# Invalid read in hash table

Tags: c, valgrind, uthash

I'm using [uthash.h](http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/userguide.html) in order to store my application's configuration. As the config comes from a file that is read at runtime, the keys and values within the hash are both dynamically allocated `char *`'s:

```
typedef struct config_entry {
    char *name;
    char *value;
    UT_hash_handle hh;
} CONFIG_ENTRY;
```

As explained in the user guide, I implemented my own function to add keys to the config-hash that ensures uniqueness. Here it is:

```
void cfg_put( char *name, char *value, FREE_FLAGS flags ) {

    CONFIG_ENTRY *entry;

    //first, check if the key is already in the hash
    HASH_FIND_STR( config_, name, entry );
    if( entry == NULL ) {
        //key doesn't exist yet => create new one
        entry = (CONFIG_ENTRY *)malloc( sizeof( CONFIG_ENTRY ) );
        entry->name = name;
        HASH_ADD_KEYPTR( hh, config_, entry->name, strlen(entry->name), entry );
    } else {
        //key exists => possibly free existing pointers before setting value

        if( (flags & FREE_NAME) == FREE_NAME ) {        //
            free( entry->name );                        // these lines seem to be
        }                                               // problematic.
        entry->name = name;                             //

        if( (flags & FREE_VALUE) == FREE_VALUE ) {
            free( entry->value );
        }
    }

    //Finally, set the value
    entry->value = value;
}
```

I also wrote up some testcases for checking my implementation, and they seem to run just fine. However, if I run the tests using valgrind to check for memleaks, I always get the following:

```
==2561== Invalid read of size 1
==2561==    at 0x4026097: bcmp (mc_replace_strmem.c:541)
==2561==    by 0x804ADF5: cfg_get (in /home/gj/..../test/config_test)
==2561==    by 0x804B2C7: test_config1 (in /home/..../test/config_test)
==2561==    by 0x402E446: run_single_test (in /usr/local/lib/libcunit.so.1.0.1)
[...]
==2561==  Address 0x4194210 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==2561==    at 0x4023B6A: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:366)
==2561==    by 0x804A872: cfg_put (in /home/..../test/config_test)
==2561==    by 0x804B27D: test_config1 (in /home/..../test/config_test)
==2561==    by 0x402E446: run_single_test (in /usr/local/lib/libcunit.so.1.0.1)
[...]
```

Here's the test case and the implementation of `cfg_get` for completeness:

```
void test_config1( void ) {

    cfg_clear( FREE_ALL );

    cfg_put( strdup("foo"), "bar", FREE_NONE );
    CU_ASSERT_EQUAL( cfg_count(), 1 );
    CU_ASSERT_STRING_EQUAL( cfg_get("foo"), "bar" );

    cfg_dump();

    cfg_put( "foo", "baz", FREE_NAME );
    CU_ASSERT_EQUAL( cfg_count(), 2 );
    CU_ASSERT_STRING_EQUAL( cfg_get("foo"), "baz" );

    cfg_clear( FREE_NONE );

    cfg_dump();
}
```

`cfg_get`:

```
char *cfg_get( const char *name ) {

    CONFIG_ENTRY *entry = NULL;
    HASH_FIND_STR( config_, name, entry );

    if( entry ) {
        return entry->value;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Somehow, it seems I'm accessing the old `name`-pointer in `cfg_get` after I've overwritten it in `cfg_put`. The problem only occurs for the `name`, not for the `value`. I'm too stupid to figure it out, thx for any advice.

Comment: Is your program multi-threaded ? It may be the issue here, variables without `volatile` flag can be moved to registers and the original memory locations may be outdated. Also does `-O` levels have an influence on your bug ?

Comment: @Grapsus No, no threads involved. I also did a build with -O0 which didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to provide the complete program — that is, a complete minimal example that reproduces the valgrind issue. The code you've posted in your question looks fine, so the bug must be hiding somewhere else; e.g. in the code of `cfg_clear()` or `cfg_count()`.

(Originally I thought that `cfg_count()` must be `return HASH_COUNT(config_);` — but that implementation wouldn't pass your test case, so you must be doing something weirder. Which means `cfg_count` is probably the wrong name for that function anyway.)

---

Stylistically, you might find your code easier to debug if you avoided the use of global variables (`config_`), and *definitely* you'd find it easier if you stored the "necessity to free this value" bits directly alongside the "value" bits, instead of requiring the user to keep track of `FREE_NAME`, `FREE_VALUE`, etc., on his own. That is, instead of

```
typedef struct config_entry {
    char *name;
    char *value;
    UT_hash_handle hh;
} CONFIG_ENTRY;

void cfg_put(char *name, char *value, FREE_FLAGS flags);
void cfg_clear(FREE_FLAGS flags);
```

you should provide merely

```
typedef struct config_entry {
    char *name;
    char *value;
    UT_hash_handle hh;
    bool must_free_name;
    bool must_free_value;
} CONFIG_ENTRY;

void cfg_put(char *name, char *value, FREE_FLAGS flags);
void cfg_clear(void);
```

at which point your test case becomes the more manageable

```
void test_config1()
{
    cfg_clear();  // use the stored bits to figure out what needs freeing
    cfg_put(strdup("foo"), "bar", FREE_NAME);  // name is alloc'ed, so name must be freed later
    CU_ASSERT_EQUAL( cfg_count(), 1 );
    CU_ASSERT_STRING_EQUAL( cfg_get("foo"), "bar" );

    cfg_put("foo", "baz", FREE_NONE);  // neither name nor value is alloc'ed
    CU_ASSERT_EQUAL( cfg_count(), 2 );
    CU_ASSERT_STRING_EQUAL( cfg_get("foo"), "baz" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your `config_put()` function: it modifies the key of an item already inserted in to the hash.  You are not supposed to do this.  It may be OK to change the `name` pointer to one that points to the same string, but it may be not, the implementation of `uthash.h` is a bit obscure.

I suggest you change the API so `config_put()` does all the string management, letting the `config_` hash own all the strings, and no longer call `strdup()` in `test_config1`. This is much simpler and avoids the potentially complicated and error prone tracking of the life cycle of string values outside of the hash structure:

```
void cfg_put(const char *name, const char *value) {

    CONFIG_ENTRY *entry;

    //first, check if the key is already in the hash
    HASH_FIND_STR(config_, name, entry);
    if (entry == NULL) {
        //key doesn't exist yet => create new one
        entry = malloc(sizeof(*entry));
        entry->name = strdup(name);
        HASH_ADD_KEYPTR(hh, config_, entry->name, strlen(entry->name), entry );
    } else {
        //key exists => free existing value pointer if any
        free(entry->value);
    }

    //Finally, set the value
    entry->value = value ? strdup(value) : NULL;
}
```